# shortcut to split "complex array" into "real" and "imaginary" arrays

Tags: python, numpy

let's say I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array((1 + 2j, 2 + 4j, 5 + 10j))
```

and I want to create two separate arrays, one of the real component, and one with the complex number component without the j.  Is there a shortcut to perform this operation in python?  the only way i can think of doing this is explicitly:

```
xr = np.zero(len(x))
xi = np.zero(len(x))
for n in range(0, len(x)):
    xr[m] = x[n].real
    xi[m] = x[n].imag
```

dunno, just seems like there should be a faster way of typing this...

like

```
xr = x.real?
xi = x.imag?
```

Comment: Have you actually tried what you're suggesting? Vectorizing this is as simple as `reals = x.real` and `x.imag`

Comment: errr....  not really... it just looked like illegal syntax... I will try.

Comment: what do you know... that actually works... python just amazes you sometimes..

Comment: `real` and `imag` are listed attributes of the `np.ndarray` datatype: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Comment: Another trick is `xr, xi = x.view('(2,)float').T` because of how `numpy` stores the data

Comment: That's pretty cool @user3483203, can u please explain what `'(2,)float'` is doing?

Comment: @yatu `numpy` just stores complex numbers as two adjacent floats, and you can get a view into this without making a copy (however transposing will make a copy).  It might be less efficient in this case because of the transpose, but something to know at least.

Comment: So the tuple is just specifying the new subarray shape, so for each row of the view, followed by the type? Was just trying to understand how the dtype specification worked :) thanks @user3483203

Comment: @user3483203 transpose returns a view, it doesn't copy data.  If you change xr[0] then the real part of x[0] will be updated. (same goes for x.real and x.imag, which are also views)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [145]: x = np.array((1 + 2j, 2 + 4j, 5 + 10j))                                    
In [146]: x                                                                          
Out[146]: array([1. +2.j, 2. +4.j, 5.+10.j])
```

The `real` and `imag` attributes work for the whole array just as well as for elements:

```
In [147]: x.real                                                                     
Out[147]: array([1., 2., 5.])
In [148]: x.imag                                                                     
Out[148]: array([ 2.,  4., 10.])
In [149]: xr, xc = x.real, x.imag                                                    
In [150]: xr                                                                         
Out[150]: array([1., 2., 5.])
In [151]: xc                                                                         
Out[151]: array([ 2.,  4., 10.])
```

The `view` approach that @user3483203 suggests, tells it to interpret the same databuffer as a sequence of two floats:

```
In [156]: x.view('(2,)float')                                                        
Out[156]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 5., 10.]])
In [157]: np.dtype('(2,)float')                                                      
Out[157]: dtype(('<f8', (2,)))
```

This notation can be obscure unless you've already worked with structured arrays and compound dtypes.